# How can I demangle or look inside readelf .symtable names?

Tags: assembly, binary, readelf

I only have access to an object file for my assignment. When I disassemble the file I can read most of the assembly, but I'm having some trouble with a few calls. A call will mention some mangled names like:

`callq  0x147 <main+206> _ZNSirsERi-0x4`

So I did some research and found that using `readelf -s 'filename'` shows the .symtable and gives me these mangled names

```
19: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZSt3cin
20: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSirsERi
21: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSolsEi
```

Is there a way to demangle this? Or find out what the -0x4 is referencing in the call?
Obviously _ZSt3cin is a cin call. But I don't know what the rest are doing.

Comment: would the `--demangle[=style]` option help?

Comment: How would I implement this? ```readelf -s 'filename' --demangle[=style]``` and ```readelf -s --demangle[=style] 'filename'``` both give errors for readelf syntax.

Comment: @Troutt025 `[=style]` means that you can optionally pass a demangling style to the option.  Just `--demangle` (i.e. `-C`) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `nm` had options that helped me.

`nm -gC 'filename'` gave me the demangled names I was looking for!

Comment: `readelf` has the same `-C` aka `--demangle` option, the default demangling style being the same one g++/clang++ use on that platform.  So does `objdump`.  e.g. `alias disas=objdump -drwC -Mintel` is a shell shortcut I find useful.